# What reason is there for the different phraseology of 1 Cor. 13:3 as expressed in different versions of the NT?

Tags: 1-corinthians

We see different versions of the NT presenting **1 Corinthians 13:3** with slightly different phraseology:

> <sup>NIV</sup> If I give all I possess to the poor and give over my body to hardship that I may boast, but do not have love, I gain nothing.

> <sup>NRSVCE</sup> If I give away all my possessions, and if I hand over my body so that I may boast, but do not have love, I gain nothing

> <sup>NKJV</sup> And though I bestow all my goods to feed the poor, and though I give my body to be burned, but have not love, it profits me nothing.

One is intrigued by the difference in phraseology in relation to giving up the body to be burned, in different versions. Is the term “burning” a figurative use, not to be taken in the literal sense?

What reason is there for these different translations?

Comment: If you were asking about different Catholic translations, then maybe it would make sense to ask for the Catholic view. But you're not, so this shouldn't be scoped to Catholicism, and instead it should be migrated to [hermeneutics.se].

Comment: Agreed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Corinthians 13:3b

NIV

> give over my body to hardship that I may **boast**

NRSVCE

> hand over my body so that I may **boast**

NKJV

> give my body to be **burned**

What reason is there for the different phraseology of 1 Cor. 13:3 as expressed in different versions of the NT?

manuscript variations.

Westcott and Hort

> παραδῶ τὸ σῶμά μου, ἵνα **καυχήσωμαι**

Stephanus Textus Receptus

> παραδῶ τὸ σῶμά μου ἵνα **καυθήσωμαι**

```
καυχήσωμαι    boast
καυθήσωμαι    burn
```

Expositor's Greek Testament explained this way:

> καυθήσωμαι [burn] is a grammatical monstrum,—a reading that cannot well be explained except as a corruption of καυχήσωμαι [boast]; it was favoured by the thought of the Christian martyrdoms, and perhaps by the influence of Daniel 3:28.

What reason is there for the different phraseology of 1 Cor. 13:3 as expressed in different versions of the NT?

This is a textual issue. Some translators favor "boast"; others prefer "burn".